# redirect multiple sub domains to single directory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I am looking for a way to distribute my images within my wordpress images folder located at
http://www.my-site.com/wp-content/uploads/ to http://img1.my-site.com/wp-content/uploads/ & http://img2.my-site.com/wp-content/uploads/ & http://img3.my-site.com/wp-content/uploads/ to increase the speed of page load by allowing the browser to download these in parallel? I have looked at htaccess redirects and rewrite and am looking for a way to direct this one folder and across the multiple sub domains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a random rewrite map: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap

You have to define it in your server/vhost config (will throw an error in your htaccess), so say you have a file like this:

**/some/path/image_hostnames.txt**

```
img    img1.my-site.com|img2.my-site.com|img3.my-site.com
```

**In the vhost/server config:**

```
RewriteMap servers rnd:/some/path/image_hostnames.txt
```

**Then in your htaccess (or server/vhost config) you setup the rewrite rules:**

```
RewriteRule ^/?wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ http://${servers:img}/wp-content/updates/$1 [L,R=301]
```

However, I'm a bit specious that this will actually *increase* page load times, since **2 connections** need to be established *per* image, the first being the request sent to `www.my-site.com`, which tells it to ask for the image at one of the `img#.my-site.com` hosts and the browser has to establish a separate connection for that. Usually, most images or other static resources can get downloaded on a single *keep-alive* connection, it's not exactly parallel, but it's also not creating a ton of connections.